# Generate output column based on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script:

```
SELECT DMC
      ,a.[id] 
      ,a.[PSN]
      ,a.[Status]
      ,a.[CreationDate]
      ,a.[DBInsertDatetime]
      ,c.Wuchtvers_anz
      ,c.[MD1_ANLIEF_MG]
      ,c.[MD2_ANLIEF_G]


FROM 
[tblTcInfo] a 
inner join [dbo].[tblC] b on a.PSN=b.PSN  
inner join [Daten] c on DMC=LGNR
   where a.PSN in (select a.PSN from [tblTcInfo] a inner join [dbo].[tblC] b on a.PSN=b.PSN  
   where DMC in
     (  

     '75044500718481203100--1802290018'

    )
```

which gives me output:

```
DMC id  PSN Status  CreationDate    DBInsertDatetime    Wuchtvers_anz   MD1_ANLIEF_MG   MD2_ANLIEF_G
00003064418481504503--1735304527    5861374 7500421056230120180527148491    1   2018-01-23 05:34:19.000 2018-01-23 05:34:19.680 2   7,72        169       
00003064418481504503--1735304527    5861374 7500421056230120180527148491    1   2018-01-23 05:34:19.000 2018-01-23 05:34:19.680 2   7,72        169
```

I expected the output:

```
DMC id  PSN Status  CreationDate    DBInsertDatetime    Wuchtvers_anz   MD1_ANLIEF_MG   MD2_ANLIEF_G    Input_column
00003064418481504503--1735304527    5861374 7500421056230120180527148491    1   2018-01-23 05:34:19.000 2018-01-23 05:34:19.680 2   7,72        169         75044500718481203100--1802290018
00003064418481504503--1735304527    5861374 7500421056230120180527148491    1   2018-01-23 05:34:19.000 2018-01-23 05:34:19.680 2   7,72        169         75044500718481203100--1802290018
```

Cannot use a solution like:

```
'75044500718481203100--1802290018' as Input_column
```

because I would have a lot of rows to input in where clause.
I've tried to use multiple `set` in combination with `declare`, but it's still doesn't work. And another option what I found, using `declare` with `insert` but here I should declare each variable. This [tblTcInfo] table is tricky!!!!!!!!!! - I can filtering 
`DMC` by ex. `2` and get `3`. Don't ask me why! so it is how it is. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why can't you alias that string? Where did that string come from? You're asking people to guess. And try to read a low-resolution image to understand what you want. Post the table schema, *actual* query you used and the expected results *as text* in the question itself. If you use SSMS as a client tool, you can copy the results and headers by clicking on the top left grid square to select all results, right click and select `Copy with Headers`

Comment: The `WHERE` clause filters data, it doesn't affect what gets selected. That's the job of the `SELECT` clause. If you want to display some input parameter there, you have to include it. That's why the source of that string is important. Is it a single parameter? A variable? Does it come from a table parameter perhaps, or another query's results?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, just added expected ouput. Input parameter is a single parameter and it comes from a table parameter

Comment: Post the *actual* code then. You have to join with the TVP to get the value from its column anyway. You can use the same column name in the SELECT clause. If you use a `WHERE IN (select ... from @tvp)` clause, you'll have to change it to something that returns the column value you want as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the only actual code that I'm using is up, and about TVP will use your recommendations, maybe you have good sample link how to do it, sorry never used it before :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rephrase the logic using a `JOIN`, so the columns you want are available to the outer query.

This is more difficult in your case, because:

- Your table aliases are not abbreviations for the table names, so the query is hard to follow.
- You do not qualify all of your column names.

Once you restructure the query, the column is available:

```
select i.DMC, i.[id], i.[PSN], i.[Status], i.CreationDate, i.[DBInsertDatetime],
       d.Wuchtvers_anz, d.MD1_ANLIEF_MG, d.MD2_ANLIEF_G,
       cc.DMC as input_DMC
from tblTcInfo i join
     [dbo].[tblC] c
     on i.PSN = c.PSN join
     Daten d
     on i.DMC = d.LGNR join -- I am guessing where these comes from
     (select distinct ?.DMC, ci.PSN
      from tblTcInfo ci join
           dbo.tblC c2
           on ci.PSN = c2.PSN 
       where ?.DMC in ('75044500718481203100--1802290018')

    ) cc
    on a.PSN = cc.PSN;
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for !!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much